# What is the equivalent of R's paste0() for raster layers?

Tags: r, raster, arcgis

I have three overlapping rasters with the same pixel size.
raster1 has the values 1-10, raster2 has the values 1-4 and raster3 has the values 1-6. I want to create a new layer that pastes their values together, to get a unique ID.
For example, for a pixel in which raster1=10, raster2=3, raster3=5 I want the output to be a raster with a pixel value of "10-3-5".

Comment: Does [merge](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/merge.html) helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique(x, as.raster=TRUE)` with "terra"

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=5, nrows=5)
values(r) <- rep(1:5, each=5)
s <- c(r, round(r/3), r+2)
```

Solution

```
u <- unique(s, as.raster=TRUE)
```

Inspect the results

```
plot(u)

u
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 5, 5, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 72, 36  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#categories  : label, lyr.1, lyr.1.1, lyr.1.2 
#name        : label 
#min value   : 1_0_3 
#max value   : 5_2_7 

levels(u)
#[[1]]
#  ID label
#1  0 1_0_3
#2  1 2_1_4
#3  2 3_1_5
#4  3 4_1_6
#5  4 5_2_7
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried it and the labels seem good, however when I compared the three input rasters to the output one it seems something is not working well? 
When I ran
`r1 <- rast(ncols=5, nrows=5) 
values(r1) <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), each=5)`
`r2 <- r1`
`r3 <- r1`
`s <- c(r1,r2,r3)`
`u <- terra::unique(s,as.raster=TRUE)`,

`levels(u)` looks like the output I needed. However, `plot(u$label)` shows that not all the lables appear in the final raster. For example 4_4_4 is missing.

Comment: That works for me, not sure why it would fail for you. Perhaps re-install the dev version?